# Experimental self inductance of a single electron (acting on itself)

Tags: electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, inductance

I have to assume that SOMEONE has figured out how to measure electron self inductance by now, but I'm not getting any search results.  Would it show up as a small apparent difference between gravitational & inertial mass?

The only explicit mentions I've been able to track down is a treatment in terms of classical Bohr orbits (http://en.fphysics.com/d/281711/d/inductance_of_the_electron.pdf) and a book that seems to be proposing a whole new theory of the nature of the electron (https://books.google.com/books?id=aenqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=electron+self+-+inductance&source=bl&ots=PBh2QhVhYl&sig=D-wZWzCIeflK6Jec2Sfvdx7YseU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5mbXOzKDXAhUNz2MKHc8VCIsQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=electron%20self%20-%20inductance&f=false).

Comment: Self-inductance is a property of macroscopic body and two points in it that describes how much emf there is between those two points when electric current flowing through the body changes in time. It makes no sense to talk about self-inductance of electron, unless the considered model of the electron allows electric current to flow *inside* the electron and there are two different points of the electron for which the emf can be defined.

Comment: Are you sure? One of the references I found shows a classical derivation of electron "self-inductance coefficient", though one of the terms (electron radius) is not precisely defined even in modern particle physics so it didn't have an actual result. It just suggested that this would be an inherent property of an electron (like spin).  Most derivations of self inductance  assume multiple charges but I've never seen a textbook explicitly state that this was part of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

In QED, the electric charge is the ability of a particle to couple with photons, e.g. emit or absorb real or virtual photons (in the Feynman diagram sense). Accordingly, "self-inductance" of the electron would refer to the ability of the electron to absorb the photons it emitted:

[image]

Also, classical electric and magnetic fields are represented in QED by the quantum electromagnetic field and classical effects like "inductance" are described in terms of transfer of energy, momentum, and spin. Therefore, in QED, the classical effect of "self-inductance" would correspond to [Self-Energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy).

There is a substantial research on the self-energy of the electron. You can easily search the web for any aspects of it that you are interested in.